# How to input multi spectral data into tensroflow

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to input the tif image with 50 channels into the tensorflow. So far I have tried the tfrecord but havn't had any luck.

I understand that there are few functions in the tensorflow to read the image.

```
decode_gif
decode_png
decode_jpeg
decode_bmp
```

but none of the above functions are capable of reading the multispectral image.

Is there any better way to input the multispectral data into tensorflow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about first convert your image into a numpy array and then convert it to a tensor? You can either pass it with feed_dict, or directly create the tensor from the numpy array.

It seems that some libraries can read tiff files, look into this : https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tifffile

In Tensorflow there is no built-in function to do that: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/12997

Comment: "What about first convert your image into a numpy array and then convert it to a tensor?" this is actually a good idea !
Thank you Adrien.